# eslint-8-4-4 error 404 to install webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, eslint

I try to install webpack at 06/30/2022 15:44 ET  and I get E404 from npm

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/eslint@https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bjvalmaseda/.npm/_logs/2022-06-30T19_42_46_230Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: v8.4.4 of @types/eslint appears to be corrupt or missing from the NPM registry: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61032

Comment: Consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821800/13897234

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through installation prev. version eslint types before Webpack installation:

```
npm i @types/eslint@8.4.3
```