# Creating React app gets some error messages

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/eslint@https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\META\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-30T20_21_05_360Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm getting this error while executing command `npx create-react-app app_name` in react.
Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821800/13897234

Comment: before initiate directory run `npm i -D @types/eslint@8.4.3` and then run the `npm create-react-app name` command. It will solve the problem